# How to set a floating point register to 0 in MIPS (or clear its value).

Tags: floating-point, mips, mips32

I'm currently implementing a square matrix multiplier containing single floating point numbers in MIPS assembly line code.

My problem is that once I am done summing the multiplications of the corresponding rows and columns in order to calculate my dot product I want to clear that floating point register so I can calculate the dot product for the next entry in the product matrix.Right now I keep adding the current dot product with all the previous dot products.

Things I've tried to set the floating point register as zero:

```
l.s $f3,$0 #loading zero into the register

addi $t0,$t0,$zero #setting a temp register as zero
l.s $f3,($t0)
```

I keep getting an error indicating a runtime exception and an address out of range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is loading a float from address 0, hence the fault. You want to load the value 0 instead. You can do that by `mtc1 $zero, $f3`. This works because all zero bits mean zero in floating point too. For other values, you'd have to do a `cvt.s.w` afterwards to convert the integer to floating point. Alternatively you can subtract the register from itself by `sub.s $f3, $f3, $f3`. Don't know if this works for all possible values (I am thinking of `NaN`, `Inf` and such) or if it is faster than transferring from the integer zero register.

Comment: `NaN - NaN` and `Inf - Inf` are NaN, not zero.  There is no FP math operation that works as a "zeroing idiom" like x86's `xor eax,eax` or `sub eax,eax`.